# Exponential Sum Approximation

Tags: exponential-function, exponential-sum

Is it possible to show mathematically that, for a short portion, sum of two decaying exponential can be approximated by a single decaying exponential? i.e.
$Ae^{-ax}+Be^{-bx}\approx Ce^{-cx}$?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math in the future. I've upgraded your post in this instance.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll definitely do that.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "a short portion".  Near $x = 0$, $$A e^{-ax} + B e^{-bx} \approx (A + B) - (A a + B b) x + \frac{A a^2 + B b^2}{2} x^2 + \ldots$$.  You might take $C$ and $c$ to fit to the first two coefficients ($C = A+B$ and $c = (A a + B b)/(A+B)$, but then the third coefficient will be wrong.  So the goodness of the approximation will be limited.

Comment: $K_1 e^{- \frac {t}{\tau_1}} + K_2 e^{- \frac {t}{\tau_2}}\approx C e^{- \frac {t}{\tau_3}}$ for $ 0<t< 100\tau_1$

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the two exponents $(a,b)$ are not "too different", what you could do, for the range $\alpha \leq x \leq \beta$,  is to minimize
$$\Phi(C,c)=\int_\alpha^\beta \Big[C e^{-c x}-A e^{-a x}-B e^{-b x} \Big]^2\, dx$$ which is equivalent to an exponential regression based on an infinite number of  data points.

The antiderivative is
$$-\frac{A^2 e^{-2 a x}}{a}-\frac{4 A B e^{-(a+b)x}}{a+b}+\frac{4 A C e^{
   -(a+c)x}}{a+c}-\frac{B^2 e^{-2 b x}}{b}+\frac{4 B C e^{
   -(b+c)x}}{b+c}-\frac{C^2 e^{-2 c x}}{c}$$

Apply the bounds to get $\Phi(C,c)$, compute the partial derivatives and set them equal to $0$.
$$\frac{\partial \Phi(C,c)}{\partial C}=0 \implies C=f(c)\qquad \text{(which is an explicit function)}$$ and you are left with
$$\frac{\partial \Phi(C,c)}{\partial c}=\frac{\partial \Phi(f(c),c)}{\partial c}=0$$ which will require some numerical method (a quite nasty nonlinear equation in $c$ but not difficult to solve using Newton method with $c_0=\frac{a+b}2$).

Probably, generating data points and using nonlinear regression could be easier since the exponential fitting is quite trivial. Generate $n$ data points $(x_i,y_i)$ with $y_i=A e^{-a x_i}+B e^{-b x_i}$ to face the model
$$y=C e^{-c x}$$ In a first step, take logarithms and a linear regression will give *estimates* of $\log(C)$ and $c$ which will be good starting values for the nonlinear regression.

For illustration, I used $A=123$, $a=0.8$, $B=234$, $b=1.1$, $\alpha=3$, $beta=5$ and generated $100$ data points. The nonlinear regression gives $(R^2 > 0.9999)$
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 A & 306.804 & 0.60903 & \{305.596,308.013\} \\
 a & 0.91475 & 0.00057 & \{0.91363,0.91587\} \\
\end{array}$$ showing a maximum absolute error of $0.06$ while the sum of the two exponentials vary between $20$ and $3$.